# How To Add Fixed Filter In Custom Admin Block Grid in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, admin, blocks, grid, admin-controller

Here is my custom grid i wan to show only those data that status is paid but now the data present with paid and unpaid both . how can i set default filter to these custom block grid...

[image]

> here is my block grid code.
> Block\Adminhtml\Custom\Grid.php

```
<?php
namespace Vrinsoft\Giftcard\Block\Adminhtml\Custom;


class Grid extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager
     */
    protected $moduleManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Set\CollectionFactory]
     */
    protected $_setsFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory
     */
    protected $_productFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type
     */
    protected $_type;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status
     */
    protected $_status;
    protected $_collectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility
     */
    protected $_visibility;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\WebsiteFactory
     */
    protected $_websiteFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\WebsiteFactory $websiteFactory
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Set\CollectionFactory $setsFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type $type
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status $status
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $visibility
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager
     * @param array $data
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper,
        \Magento\Store\Model\WebsiteFactory $websiteFactory,
        \Vrinsoft\Giftcard\Model\ResourceModel\Custom\Collection $collectionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        
        $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->_websiteFactory = $websiteFactory;
        $this->moduleManager = $moduleManager;
        parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        
        $this->setId('productGrid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        $this->setUseAjax(false);
       
    }

    /**
     * @return Store
     */
    protected function _getStore()
    {
        $storeId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0);
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore($storeId);
    }

    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        try{
            
            
            $collection =$this->_collectionFactory->load();

          

            $this->setCollection($collection);

            parent::_prepareCollection();
          
            return $this;
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();die;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column $column
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _addColumnFilterToCollection($column)
    {
        if ($this->getCollection()) {
            if ($column->getId() == 'websites') {
                $this->getCollection()->joinField(
                    'websites',
                    'catalog_product_website',
                    'website_id',
                    'product_id=entity_id',
                    null,
                    'left'
                );
            }
        }
        return parent::_addColumnFilterToCollection($column);
    }

    /**
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn(
            'id',
            [
                'header' => __('ID'),
                'type' => 'number',
                'index' => 'id',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-id'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'order_id',
            [
                'header' => __('order_id'),
                'index' => 'order_id',
                'class' => 'order_id'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'customer_id',
            [
                'header' => __('customer_id'),
                'index' => 'customer_id',
                'class' => 'customer_id'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'product_id',
            [
                'header' => __('product_id'),
                'index' => 'product_id',
                'class' => 'product_id'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'name',
            [
                'header' => __('name'),
                'index' => 'name',
                'class' => 'name'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'email',
            [
                'header' => __('email'),
                'index' => 'email',
                'class' => 'email'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'phone',
            [
                'header' => __('phone'),
                'index' => 'phone',
                'class' => 'phone'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'description',
            [
                'header' => __('description'),
                'index' => 'description',
                'class' => 'description'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'status',
            [
                'header' => __('status'),
                'index' => 'status',
                'class' => 'status'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'redemestatus',
            [
                'header' => __('redemestatus'),
                'index' => 'redemestatus',
                'class' => 'redemestatus'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'price',
            [
                'header' => __('price'),
                'index' => 'price',
                'class' => 'price'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'redemecode',
            [
                'header' => __('redemecode'),
                'index' => 'redemecode',
                'class' => 'redemecode'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'currentdate',
            [
                'header' => __('currentdate'),
                'index' => 'currentdate',
                'type' => 'date',
            ]
        );
        /*{{CedAddGridColumn}}*/

        $block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('grid.bottom.links');
        if ($block) {
            $this->setChild('grid.bottom.links', $block);
        }

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

     /**
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareMassaction()
    {
        $this->setMassactionIdField('id');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('id');

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem(
            'delete',
            array(
                'label' => __('Delete'),
                'url' => $this->getUrl('giftcard/*/massDelete'),
                'confirm' => __('Are you sure?')
            )
        );
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('giftcard/*/index', ['_current' => true]);
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product|\Magento\Framework\Object $row
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        return $this->getUrl(
            'giftcard/*/edit',
            ['store' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('store'), 'id' => $row->getId()]
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your collection add these below function

\Model\ResourceModel\Custom\Collection.php

```
/**
     * Add filter by status code(s) to collection
     *
     * @param string|string[] $status
     * @return $this
     */
    public function loadByStatus($status)
    {
        if (!empty($status)) {
            if (is_array($status)) {
                $this->addFieldToFilter("status", ['in' => $status]);
            } else {
                $this->addFieldToFilter("status", $status);
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

And load you collection on grid like that

Block\Adminhtml\Custom\Grid.php

```
 /**
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        try{
            
            
            // $collection =$this->_collectionFactory->addAttributeToFilter('status', ['eq'=>'paid'])->load();

            $collection =$this->_collectionFactory->loadByStatus('paid');

          

            $this->setCollection($collection);

            parent::_prepareCollection();
          
            return $this;
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();die;
        }
    }
```